# Whitespace in the bottom of the screen of jquery mobile web application?

Tags: android, css, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing an app with JQM 1.1 and Phonegap 1.8, I use JavaScript to render HTML. Sometimes a white space randomly appears at the bottom of the page. I have tried number of CSS fixes but nothing seems to help.

iPad screenshot:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/7068306/photo.PNG

This happens on Android and iOS.

Comment: are you talking about the off-white space or is there a gap below that? i ask because its displaying against a white webpage background so i wanna make sure im looking at the correct space.

Comment: I just updated the screenshot, should be easier to spot the whitespace now.

Comment: post the css and html for that page

Comment: the page gets dynamically rendered on the mobile device and uses standard JQM styles, I only have couple custom button styles in another css file. I have modified the Phonegap Build config.xml to not allow screen bounce in iOS and it look like it has partially solved the problem, so this might be linked to the iOS and Android WebView implementation.